# How do you select rows from a mysql DB where a column begins with a number?

Tags: mysql

Beginning with a letter I know how to do:

```
WHERE mov_title REGEXP CONCAT('^(the )?', '$letter')
```

And this method will work if I substitute $letter with any number, so if its set to 1, it will find all records that begin with 1, but I need it to work for any number 0-9. How could I modify the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE mov_title REGEXP '^(the )?[0-9]'
```

(Or set `$letter` to `[0-9]` if you want to keep using your existing `WHERE` clause.)

Answer (score 3):

Another option may be to use the substring function

```
WHERE substring( post_title, 1, 1 ) between '0' and '9'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps SQL Wild cards [charlist] might help:

http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp